# Call bash function on its result a given amount of times

Tags: bash, shell

I need to call a bash function on the output of calling it on a given argument. This process is to be repeated a prescribed amount of times. Is there a quick and elegant way to do it?

Comment: Probably just a loop that calls `result=$(myFunc "$result")` repeatedly, but more detail about the function might suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the script below. I have tried to answer your question based on what I could understand. If this does not answer your question then try to provide me with some explanation which might help me to give you a better answer.

What I have done below is created two functions, taking output from second funtion and calling a bash function named "first".

```
#! /bin/bash
function first() {
echo "Print Second Function Output: " $1    # "$1" prints the argument passed by function "second"
}
function second() {
var=$(pwd)
first $var    # Calling function "first" using output of funtion "second" 
}
second
```

Comment: The problem is that while the input is a single number the first time, the subsequent  times it will be more numbers, space separated or newline separated. In this case the second call won't work.